# ld ignores additional pathes

Tags: c++, ld

I'm am trying to compile a C++ program that uses Gurobi. The problem is that ld cannot find the library although ldconfig sees it. I also tried to configure the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable without success

```
$ sudo ldconfig -v
...
/opt/gurobi701/linux64/lib:
        libgurobi.so.7.0.1 -> libgurobi.so.7.0.1
        libaes70.so -> libaes70.so
        libGurobiJni70.so -> libGurobiJni70.so
...

$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
:/opt/gurobi701/linux64/lib

$ ld -lgurobi_c++ --verbose
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1
  Émulations prises en charge :
   elf_x86_64
   elf32_x86_64
   elf_i386
   elf_iamcu
   i386linux
   elf_l1om
   elf_k1om
   i386pep
   i386pe
utilisation du script interne d'édition de liens :
==================================================
/* Script for -z combreloc: combine and sort reloc sections */
/* Copyright (C) 2014-2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   Copying and distribution of this script, with or without modification,
   are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
   notice and this notice are preserved.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-x86-64", "elf64-x86-64",
          "elf64-x86-64")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:x86-64)
ENTRY(_start)
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib");
SECTIONS
{
  /* Read-only sections, merged into text segment: */
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  .interp         : { *(.interp) }
  .note.gnu.build-id : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
  .hash           : { *(.hash) }
  .gnu.hash       : { *(.gnu.hash) }
  .dynsym         : { *(.dynsym) }
  .dynstr         : { *(.dynstr) }
  .gnu.version    : { *(.gnu.version) }
  .gnu.version_d  : { *(.gnu.version_d) }
  .gnu.version_r  : { *(.gnu.version_r) }
  .rela.dyn       :
    {
      *(.rela.init)
      *(.rela.text .rela.text.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
      *(.rela.fini)
      *(.rela.rodata .rela.rodata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.r.*)
      *(.rela.data .rela.data.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.d.*)
      *(.rela.tdata .rela.tdata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.td.*)
      *(.rela.tbss .rela.tbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.tb.*)
      *(.rela.ctors)
      *(.rela.dtors)
      *(.rela.got)
      *(.rela.bss .rela.bss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.b.*)
      *(.rela.ldata .rela.ldata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.l.*)
      *(.rela.lbss .rela.lbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.lb.*)
      *(.rela.lrodata .rela.lrodata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.lr.*)
      *(.rela.ifunc)
    }
  .rela.plt       :
    {
      *(.rela.plt)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rela_iplt_start = .);
      *(.rela.iplt)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rela_iplt_end = .);
    }
  .init           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.init)))
  }
  .plt            : { *(.plt) *(.iplt) }
.plt.got        : { *(.plt.got) }
.plt.bnd        : { *(.plt.bnd) }
  .text           :
  {
    *(.text.unlikely .text.*_unlikely .text.unlikely.*)
    *(.text.exit .text.exit.*)
    *(.text.startup .text.startup.*)
    *(.text.hot .text.hot.*)
    *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    /* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf32.em.  */
    *(.gnu.warning)
  }
  .fini           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.fini)))
  }
  PROVIDE (__etext = .);
  PROVIDE (_etext = .);
  PROVIDE (etext = .);
  .rodata         : { *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*) }
  .rodata1        : { *(.rodata1) }
  .eh_frame_hdr : { *(.eh_frame_hdr) *(.eh_frame_entry .eh_frame_entry.*) }
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RO { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) *(.eh_frame.*) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gcc_except_table
  .gcc_except_table.*) }
  .gnu_extab   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gnu_extab*) }
  /* These sections are generated by the Sun/Oracle C++ compiler.  */
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.exception_ranges
  .exception_ranges*) }
  /* Adjust the address for the data segment.  We want to adjust up to
     the same address within the page on the next page up.  */
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE), CONSTANT (COMMONPAGESIZE));
  /* Exception handling  */
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RW { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) *(.eh_frame.*) }
  .gnu_extab      : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gnu_extab) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gcc_except_table .gcc_except_table.*) }
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.exception_ranges .exception_ranges*) }
  /* Thread Local Storage sections  */
  .tdata      : { *(.tdata .tdata.* .gnu.linkonce.td.*) }
  .tbss       : { *(.tbss .tbss.* .gnu.linkonce.tb.*) *(.tcommon) }
  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  }
  .init_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.init_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  }
  .fini_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.fini_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  }
  .ctors          :
  {
    /* gcc uses crtbegin.o to find the start of
       the constructors, so we make sure it is
       first.  Because this is a wildcard, it
       doesn't matter if the user does not
       actually link against crtbegin.o; the
       linker won't look for a file to match a
       wildcard.  The wildcard also means that it
       doesn't matter which directory crtbegin.o
       is in.  */
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.ctors))
    /* We don't want to include the .ctor section from
       the crtend.o file until after the sorted ctors.
       The .ctor section from the crtend file contains the
       end of ctors marker and it must be last */
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.ctors))
  }
  .dtors          :
  {
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.dtors))
  }
  .jcr            : { KEEP (*(.jcr)) }
  .data.rel.ro : { *(.data.rel.ro.local* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.local.*) *(.data.rel.ro .data.rel.ro.* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.*) }
  .dynamic        : { *(.dynamic) }
  .got            : { *(.got) *(.igot) }
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_RELRO_END (SIZEOF (.got.plt) >= 24 ? 24 : 0, .);
  .got.plt        : { *(.got.plt)  *(.igot.plt) }
  .data           :
  {
    *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
    SORT(CONSTRUCTORS)
  }
  .data1          : { *(.data1) }
  _edata = .; PROVIDE (edata = .);
  . = .;
  __bss_start = .;
  .bss            :
  {
   *(.dynbss)
   *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
   *(COMMON)
   /* Align here to ensure that the .bss section occupies space up to
      _end.  Align after .bss to ensure correct alignment even if the
      .bss section disappears because there are no input sections.
      FIXME: Why do we need it? When there is no .bss section, we don't
      pad the .data section.  */
   . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 64 / 8 : 1);
  }
  .lbss   :
  {
    *(.dynlbss)
    *(.lbss .lbss.* .gnu.linkonce.lb.*)
    *(LARGE_COMMON)
  }
  . = ALIGN(64 / 8);
  . = SEGMENT_START("ldata-segment", .);
  .lrodata   ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) + (. & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)) :
  {
    *(.lrodata .lrodata.* .gnu.linkonce.lr.*)
  }
  .ldata   ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) + (. & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)) :
  {
    *(.ldata .ldata.* .gnu.linkonce.l.*)
    . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 64 / 8 : 1);
  }
  . = ALIGN(64 / 8);
  _end = .; PROVIDE (end = .);
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_END (.);
  /* Stabs debugging sections.  */
  .stab          0 : { *(.stab) }
  .stabstr       0 : { *(.stabstr) }
  .stab.excl     0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
  .stab.exclstr  0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
  .stab.index    0 : { *(.stab.index) }
  .stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
  .comment       0 : { *(.comment) }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
  /* DWARF 1 */
  .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
  .line           0 : { *(.line) }
  /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
  .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
  .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
  .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
  .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
  /* DWARF 2 */
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line .debug_line.* .debug_line_end ) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions */
  .debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
  .debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
  .debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
  .debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
  /* DWARF 3 */
  .debug_pubtypes 0 : { *(.debug_pubtypes) }
  .debug_ranges   0 : { *(.debug_ranges) }
  /* DWARF Extension.  */
  .debug_macro    0 : { *(.debug_macro) }
  .gnu.attributes 0 : { KEEP (*(.gnu.attributes)) }
  /DISCARD/ : { *(.note.GNU-stack) *(.gnu_debuglink) *(.gnu.lto_*) }
}


==================================================
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgurobi_c++.so
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgurobi_c++.a
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgurobi_c++.so
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgurobi_c++.a
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgurobi_c++.so
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgurobi_c++.a
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //usr/local/lib64/libgurobi_c++.so
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //usr/local/lib64/libgurobi_c++.a
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //lib64/libgurobi_c++.so
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //lib64/libgurobi_c++.a
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //usr/lib64/libgurobi_c++.so
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //usr/lib64/libgurobi_c++.a
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //usr/local/lib/libgurobi_c++.so
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //usr/local/lib/libgurobi_c++.a
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //lib/libgurobi_c++.so
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //lib/libgurobi_c++.a
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //usr/lib/libgurobi_c++.so
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //usr/lib/libgurobi_c++.a
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libgurobi_c++.so
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libgurobi_c++.a
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libgurobi_c++.so
échec de la tentative d'ouverture de //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libgurobi_c++.a
ld : ne peut trouver -lgurobi_c++
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44990/what-is-the-difference-between-path-and-ld-library-path) is the path where the dynamic *loader* (`ld.so` and `ld-linux.so` on Linux, `dyld` on OS X) looks up libraries. You need this when you run programs that depend on libraries in non-standard paths.

It doesn't necessarily influence where the *linker* finds libraries. Use the `-L` flag to specify the search path for `ld`:

```
ld -L/opt/gurobi701/linux64/lib -lgurobi_c++ ...
```

Comment: Is there a way to not add the -L option to the ld command? I'd like the compilation to work even if Gurobi has not been installed in /opt/gurobi701/linux64/lib as long as the path of the library has been defined at the system level

Comment: If Gurobi works with `pkg-config`, you could use something like `$(pkg-config --libs gurobi)` instead of the linker flags. Not sure if it does, however. Otherwise, you'd need to find the path manually somehow (maybe there are some binaries that you could `which` for, or use `find`?)

Comment: Actually, I use Bazel for the compilation and I'd like the code to be multi-platform. So I'd prefer not to use pkg-config or any unix specific commands

Comment: Some additional comment: When compiling with `gcc`, the variable `LIBRARY_PATH` can be used to add directories where the linker will search for libraries during the linking step. Unfortunately, this variable is not taken into account when `ld` is invoked directly