# How to make ld see additional file paths

Tags: ld

I'm trying to get ld to see a path where I have a .so installed. There's another [similar post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14862913/3626104) which I've been following.

In my case, I need the paths controlled by environment variable, just like the other person posting.

There's also another answer in a different post which recommends using [pkg-config to auto-find the paths needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318805/ld-ignores-additional-pathes#comment87653656_50318836). But again, that won't work for me because it'd require changing source code, and the solution needs to be configuration-based (environment variable, ideally).

### What I Tried

Setting `LIBRARY_PATH` and/or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the directory doesn't work.

Using -L **does** work but I can't use it, because the solution must be configuration-based (no execution flags)

```
ld -lxcb-keysyms --verbose -L`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`  # This finds the path I need
LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ld -lxcb-keysyms --verbose  # This doesn't find it.
```

I've also tried modifying my path to include or not include the "lib64" folder in the environment variable like one of the answers pointed out. This doesn't work. Anyone know what I need to do to get this working?

### System specs

```
$lsb_release --all
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
Release:        7.6.1810
Codename:       Core
```

Comment: It's unclear why you have a problem. Why do you consider `-Ldir` an "execution flag"
but not `-lname`? `LIBRARY_PATH` has no meaning for `ld` but is significant for `gcc`. So why don't you link using `gcc`? And you'd have to be assigning or appending `/the/right/path` to `LIBRARY_PATH` at some point anyhow in the inherited environment of the `ld` process, if it *was* significant; so why can't you assign `THE_RIGHT_PATH=/the/right/path`at the same point and then run `ld ... $(THE_RIGHT_PATH)/libxcb-keysyms.so ...`?

Comment: I'm still catching up on the docs for all this so I probably have some concepts confused. The tool I'm compiling with `make` already defines `-lname` which is why I don't mind that it's there. But adding `-L` would require me to manually add it via `LDFLAGS` or patch the Makefile directly. Instead of doing something that'd dependent on the Makefile, I'd like to know how to set my environment so I don't need to change any of the program's source code.

Comment: [This is the project, by the way](https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd/blob/master/Makefile#L8)

Comment: the `ld(1)` man page seems to indicate that `LD_RUN_PATH` might serve your need.